# No sé cómo sacar solo una imagen por producto en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una lista de productos para una tienda en línea y cada producto tiene varias imágenes, pero en el listado de los productos están saliendo todos las imágenes de los productos y yo solo necesito que salga una imagen por producto. El `distinct` no me funciona.

Envío un fragmento del código:

```
<ul id="portfolioPaginationWrapper" class="portfolio-list sort-destination" data-sort-id="portfolio" data-items-per-page="8">
                        <?


                             $result2 = qry("select products.id, title, text, cat, price, products_img.img from products left join products_img on products.id = products_img.productsid where idpage = $id_pagina");

                                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){



?>


                            <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 isotope-item <?=$row3['cat'];?>">
                                <div class="portfolio-item">
                                    <a href="portfolio-single-small-slider.html">
                                        <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-lighten">
                                            <span class="thumb-info-wrapper">
                                                <img src="../includes/img.php?img=<?=$id_pagina?>/<?=$row3['img'];?>&x=1000&y=1000&t=1" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-title">
                                                    <span class="thumb-info-inner"><?=$row3['title'];?></span>
                                                    <span class="thumb-info-type">$<?=$row3['price'];?></span>
                                                </span>

                                                <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                                    <span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?
                        }

                    ?>  
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar la siguiente query, actualmente lo que haces es traer todas las imagenes que están asociadas al producto, espero te sirva.

```
    $result2 = qry("SELECT 
  products.id,
  title,
  text,
  cat,
  price,
  (SELECT products_img.img FROM products_img WHERE products.id = products_img.productsid LIMIT 1) AS imagen_producto
FROM
  products 
WHERE idpage = $ id_pagina");
```